# How to get the values in a dynamic table?

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic table as in here: http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/q524G/2/ . 
I would like to get 2 values from each row in the table. So I created 2 variables as:

```
fbType = $('td.nth(2)', $(this)).html();
fbNum = $('td.nth(3)', $(this)).html();
```

Then to display them, I tried:

```
$('#test').append(fbType + fbNum);
```

But nothing ever appear. 
How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` inside `monitor` does not point to the `tr`, so pass the `tr` as a parameter and try

```
$('#monitor').click(function () {
    $('#status_table tr').each(function () {
    $check = $('input:checkbox', this)
        if ($check.is(':checked')) {
            monitoring(this);
        }
    });
});

function monitoring(el) {
    $('#test').append("checked");
    fbType = $('td:nth-child(1)', el).html();
    fbNum = $('td:nth-child(2)', el).html();

    $('#test').append(fbType + fbNum);

    $.post('/request', {
        inputText: fbNum,
        key_pressed: fbType.toString()
    }).done(function (reply) {
        if (reply == "on") {
            $('#test').append("on ");
        } else {
            $('#test').append("off ");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: oh yes it works! Thanks again Arun! :D you've helped me a lot!! Thank you :)